# Wordpress $wpdb->query() inserts multiple rows with duplicate data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am experiencing very strange problem with wordpress query() function.

I have a form on page 1 where below code to insert a new record.

```
if(isset($_POST["transaction_id"])){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( " INSERT INTO `{$wpdb->prefix}v_cards` (transaction_id, user_id) VALUES ( %d, %d)", $_POST['transaction_id'], $_POST['user_id']);
    $wpdb->query($sql);
    $_SESSION['card_id'] = $wpdb->insert_id;
}


And on submit below Update query fires to update a row
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare('UPDATE '.$wpdb->prefix.'v_cards SET
                                        prefix=%s,
                                        first_name=%s,
                                        middle_name=%s,
                                        last_name=%s,
                                        suffix=%s,
                                        degree=%s,
                                        description=%s,
                                        copyright=%s,
                                        background=%s,
                                        photo=%s,
                                        call_country_code=%s,
                                        call_number=%s,
                                        call_ext=%s,
                                        call_activate=%s,
                                        text_country_code=%s,
                                        text_number=%s,
                                        text_ext=%s,
                                        text_activate=%s,
                                        email=%s,
                                        email_activate=%s,
                                        find_location_name=%s,
                                        find_address_1=%s,
                                        find_address_2=%s,
                                    find_city=%s,
                                    find_state=%s,
                                    find_postcode=%s,
                                    find_country_code=%s,
                                    find_activate=%s,
                                    profile_details=%s,
                                    profile_activate=%s,
                                    organization=%s,
                                    org_industry=%s,
                                    org_country=%s,
                                    org_address_1=%s,
                                    org_address_2=%s,
                                    org_city=%s,
                                    org_state=%s,
                                    org_postcode=%s,
                                    org_phone=%s,
                                    org_fax=%s,
                                    org_email=%s,
                                        org_details=%s,
                                        org_activate=%s,
                                        contact_location_name=%s,
                                        contact_country=%s,
                                        contact_address_1=%s,
                                        contact_address_2=%s,
                                        contact_city=%s,
                                        contact_state=%s,
                                        contact_postcode=%s,
                                        contact_phone=%s,
                                        contact_fax=%s,
                                        contact_email=%s,
                                        contact_activate=%s,
                                        my_sites_title=%s,
                                        my_sites_url=%s,
                                        my_sites_activate=%s,
                                        social_title=%s,
                                        social_url=%s,
                                        social_activate=%s,
                                        icon=%s,
                                        card_name=%s,
                                        card_status=%s,
                                        modify_date=SYSDATE()
                                    WHERE id = %s', $_POST['prefix'], $_POST['first_name'], $_POST['middle_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['suffix'], $_POST['degree'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['copyright'], $background_id, $icon_id, $_POST['call_country_code'], $_POST['call_number'], $_POST['call_ext'], $_POST['call_activate'], $_POST['text_country_code'], $_POST['text_number'], $_POST['text_ext'], $_POST['text_activate'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['email_activate'], $_POST['find_location_name'], $_POST['find_address_1'], $_POST['find_address_2'], $_POST['find_city'], $_POST['find_state'], $_POST['find_postcode'], $_POST['find_country_code'], $_POST['find_activate'], $_POST['profile_details'], $_POST['profile_activate'], $_POST['organization'], $_POST['org_industry'], $_POST['org_country'], $_POST['org_address_1'], $_POST['org_address_2'], $_POST['org_city'], $_POST['org_state'], $_POST['org_postcode'], $_POST['org_phone'], $_POST['org_fax'], $_POST['org_email'], $_POST['org_details'], $_POST['org_activate'], $_POST['contact_location_name'], $_POST['country_contact'], $_POST['contact_address_1'], $_POST['contact_address_2'], $_POST['contact_city'], $_POST['contact_state'], $_POST['contact_postcode'], $_POST['contact_phone'], $_POST['contact_fax'], $_POST['contact_email'], $_POST['contact_activate'], $_POST['my_sites_title'], $_POST['my_sites_url'], $_POST['my_sites_activate'], $_POST['social_title'], $_POST['social_url'], $_POST['social_activate'], $icon_id, $_POST['card_name'], $_POST['card_status'], $_SESSION['card_id']);

    $wpdb->query($sql);
```

but instead when I submit form and it will insert a new row and also updates an old row
All code written in a Wordpress widget (Second Top widgets Area).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm little confused about where you have this code? It looks to me that both "if(isset($_POST["transaction_id"])){" and "$sql = $wpdb->prepare('UPDATE '.$wpdb->prefix." are on SUBMIT. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, both are on SUBMIT but on different widgets.

Comment: I don't have much experience with widget development, so I'm unable to help you. You could try your question in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable xdebug if it's activated. Same bug happened to me while xdebug is active.